# Building a regex in php

Tags: php, regex

Is it possible to write a regular expression that would match any words in a string that have TWO capital letters in the beginning of them.

Like:

$string = "DEar John"

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use the `upper` character class, which refers to uppercase characters:

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php

```
([[:upper:]][[:upper:]][[:alpha:]]*)
```

Tested on http://regex101.com/ in PHP PCRE mode.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to label in your question "match any words in a string that have two capital letters in the beginning of them", you can use the [Unicode Property `\p{Lu}`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) which matches an uppercase letter that has a lowercase variant and the [Unicode Property `\p{Ll}`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) which matches a lowercase letter that has an uppercase variant.

```
/\p{Lu}{2}[\pLu\pLl]*/u
```

However, you could as well go with a basic regular expression.

```
/[A-Z]{2}(?i:[a-z]*)/
```